# MapView only loads twice and then no MAP apears, only yellow background

Tags: ios, mkmapview, nstimer

Mapview loads successfully when the app loads.

Then, after changing views and returning to the main view the first time and viewDidAppear initializes, Mapview loads successfully.

But after the first instance of viewDidAppear, the mapview map does not load and the background is yellow. I have to restart the app before the mapview map appears again.

Is this because I am not releasing the mapview properly when changing views? I am using ARC.

Edit(katzenhut): The OP posted this code in a comment:
Appdelegate.m

```
if(self.locationManager==nil){
     _locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     _locationManager.delegate=self;
     self.locationManager = _locationManager;
 }
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{


    [self setValuesFromPreferences];
    appDelegate.refresh = FALSE;
    theMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [theMapView setCenterCoordinate:appDelegate.locationManager.location.coordinate   zoomLevel:zoom animated:YES];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
    [theMapView setCenterCoordinate: appDelegate.locationManager.location.coordinate zoomLevel:zoom animated: YES];
}
```

Mapviewcontroller.m

```
#import "MapViewController.h"


@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize theMapView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    appDelegate = (theAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    theMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    pendingRegionChange = YES;
    isTracking = YES;
    [theMapView setCenterCoordinate:appDelegate.locationManager.location.coordinate zoomLevel:14 animated:YES];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if( isTracking )
    {
        pendingRegionChange = YES;
        [theMapView setCenterCoordinate:appDelegate.locationManager.location.coordinate zoomLevel:14 animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if( isTracking && ! pendingRegionChange )
    {
        isTracking = NO;
    }

    pendingRegionChange = NO;
}

@end
```

Resolved Problem with the following code in viewcontroller.m:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: could you add some code to clarify?

Comment: please put that as an edit into your post and format it properly.

Comment: Sorry, first time posting. Code is attached now.

Comment: This is still not resolved. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Strange as it may sound. It had nothing to do with the MapView. I had an NSTimer that was not stopped when I changed views.